# ServletException : tmpFile.renameTo(classFile) failed

Tags: jsp, jboss7.x, servletexception, temporary-files

After deploying a war to JBOSS 7.1.0 I am facing an exception mentioned below. An error message

> '[ServletException in:/WEB-INF/modules/pages/SomeJspPage.jsp] tmpFile.renameTo(classFile) failed'

is shown in jsp page and below exception is generated on server.log

Found that when Jboss server is restarted, the problem get solved with that particular page but may comes to any other jsp pages.

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/mps].[jsp]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: java.io.IOException: tmpFile.renameTo(classFile) failed
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil$SDEInstaller.install(SmapUtil.java:246) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil.installSmap(SmapUtil.java:165) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:461) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:607) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:734) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:639) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:576) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:621) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:137) [struts.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:177) [struts.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:756) [struts.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:881) [struts.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:473) [struts.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.modules.main.tiles.CustomBase_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005fget_005f2(CustomBase_jsp.java:289)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.modules.main.tiles.CustomBase_jsp._jspService(CustomBase_jsp.java:181)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:734) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:541) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:479) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:407) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069) [struts.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:274) [struts.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:254) [struts.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:309) [struts.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279) [struts.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482) [struts.jar:1.1]
at com.montran.main.action.InheritanceActionServet.process(InheritanceActionServet.java:332) [classes:]
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507) [struts.jar:1.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:734) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:541) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:479) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:407) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069) [struts.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:274) [struts.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455) [struts.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:320) [struts.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279) [struts.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482) [struts.jar:1.1]
at com.montran.main.action.InheritanceActionServet.process(InheritanceActionServet.java:332) [classes:]
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507) [struts.jar:1.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at com.montran.security.ActivityLoggingFilter.doFilter(ActivityLoggingFilter.java:86) [classes:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at com.montran.security.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:176) [classes:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
```

Can anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: There are a couple of similar questions on SO. Did you try the solutions posted there? One of them being [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364931/tomcat-jsp-page-not-compiling-java-io-ioexception-tmpfile-renametoclassfile)

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work